# Custom compile function removes two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an attribute directive `my-directive` in my Angular 1.5.8 app. I want to add it to an element and also I'd like to pass two extra parameters, one with `one-way` binding (`@`), the other with `two-way` binding (`=`).

It works fine until I try to customize the directive's compile function to add extra attributes. The `one-way`binding still works fine, but the `two-way` binding just disappears.

Here's the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/SH4dMs?p=preview).

If I comment out the compile function, it works again. I guess I'm overwriting the default behavior somehow, but I can't figure out how to prevent that.

My compile function:

```
compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
  return {
    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {},
    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
      if (!iAttrs.compiled) {
        iElement.attr('compiled', true);
        iElement.attr('ng-click', "$ctrl.onClick()");
        $compile(iElement)(scope);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a precise answer for why this is behaving like that but the compile will only works on children elements with your current set. So you can solve the problem by just changing your `$compile(...` to the following code.

```
$compile(iElement.children())(scope);
```

#### UPDATE 1

Apparently, the `iElement` has its scope already defined by the parent scope. Therefore, the compile will not be able use the element because the isolated scope only works within the directive.

However, the issue now is how to add new directives in compile phase? You could do this by changing your directive to the following code:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      terminal: true,
      priority: 1001,
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        myObject: '=myObject',
        text: '@text'
      },
      transclude: true,
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function() {
        var $ctrl = this;
        $ctrl.onClick = onClick;
        return $ctrl;

        function onClick() {
          alert("clicked");
        }
      },
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      template: '<pre>{{$ctrl}}</pre> {{ $ctrl.text }} - {{ $ctrl.myObject.attr1 }}',
      compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
        element.removeAttr("my-directive");
        element.attr('compiled', true);
        element.attr('ng-click', "$ctrl.onClick()");
        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {},
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            $compile(iElement)(scope);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, this indeed works. However, I'd rather not remove the directive attribute from the element. Eventually I added an event listener in the linker function, I think that's the best approach.